# In SQL, how find the total of a row over time?

Tags: sql

A table and I want to know the total of my rows over time. For example.  Here's my table:

```
Date   Fruit   Sold
Mon    apple   4
Mon    pear    5
Mon    orange  2
Tues   apple   3
Tues   pear    2
Tues   orange  1

The table I want back is:
Fruit   Sold
apple   7
pear    7
orange  3
```

What is a query that I can do this? However, with my real situation, I have hundreds of types of fruit. So how do I query with out specifying each type of fruit each time?

Comment: This looks like homework. If it is, please tag with `homework`.

Answer (score 2):

That would be along the lines of:

```
select fruit, sum(sold) as sold
from fruitsales
group by fruit
-- adding something like <<where date = 'Mon'>> if you want to limit it.
```

This will aggregate the individual `sold` columns (by summing) for each `fruit` type.

Answer (score 2):

here is how to do it:

```
select fruit, sum(sold)
from table
group by fruit
```

cheers...

Answer (score 0):

**Group by Time**

```
select fruit, sum(sold),substring(saletime,1,3) from table group by fruit,substring(saletime,1,3)
```